# The view 'Index' or its master was not found.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.aspx
~/Views/ControllerName/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
```

I got this error when using ASP.Net mvc area. The area controller action are invoked, but it seems to look for the view in the 'base' project views instead of in the area views folder.

Comment: @çağdaş: Its ASP.NET MVC2 RC2.

Comment: Did you find a way to get round this or did you just give up on MVCContribs MvcRoute?  Having the same problem

Comment: I just returned to the 'regular' `routes.MapRoute()` at the time. But **now** you can use the updated MvcContrib that fully support mvc2.

Comment: Thanks Mendy.  I'll give it another go.  Could just be me being a noob missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I used `MvcRoute.MappUrl` from `MvcContrib` to route the `context.Routes`.

It seems that `MvcContrib` routing mapper was uncomfortable with area routing.

Comment: Can you please add more info about the problem and its solution? Please add any code example, if you can.

Answer (score 53):

What you need to do is set a token to your area name:

for instance:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "SomeArea_default",
        "SomeArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "SomeController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).DataTokens.Add("area", "YOURAREANAME");
```

Comment: Couldn't find my chrome tab fast enough to upvote this when it worked for me in MVC4 =)

Comment: Who would have thought?     No seriously, who??? This seriously obscure issue halted me for hours! Thanks @Shannon

Comment: Worked for me in MVC4. `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { area = "General", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );` was not enough. Adding `DataToken` was necessary.

Comment: I tried everything to make Areas work and this is the only answer that helped me.

Comment: what is area and YOURAREANAME? where can we find it?

Comment: Worked for me in MVC5

Comment: MYAMANAME? Consider renaming =p

Answer (score 29):

This error was raised because your Controller method name is not same as the View's name.

If you right click on your controller method and select Go To View (Ctrl+M,Ctrl+G), it will either open a View (success) or complain that it couldn't find one (what you're seeing).

1. Corresponding Controllers and View folders name have the same names.
2. Corresponding Controller methods & Views pages should same have the same names.
3. If your method name is different than view name, `return view("viewName")` in the method.

Comment: Thanks. As stated (bullet #1) Index.cshtml was in Views folder root when it should have been in Views\[ControllerName] folder. Adding subfolder and putting view inside fixed error.

Answer (score 14):

Global.asax file contain the URL Route.
Default URL route like this.

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

**So,Try this.**

***1. Right click your controller method as below.***

Example: let say we call `Index()` method.Right click on it.
[image]

***2. Click Add View.. and give appropriate name.In this example name should be Index.***

[image]

Then it will add correct View by creating with relevant folder structure.

Answer (score 10):

Check the generated code at *MyArea*AreaRegistration.cs and make sure that the controller parameter is set to your default controller, otherwise the controller will be called bot for some reason ASP.NET MVC won't search for the views at the area folder

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "SomeArea_default",
            "SomeArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "SomeController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Where this error only occurs when deployed to a web server then the issue could be because the views are not being deployed correctly.

An example of how this can happen is if the build action for the views is set to None rather than Content.

A way to check that the views are deployed correctly is to navigate to the physical path for the site on the web server and confirm that the views are present.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely did not create your own view engine.
The default view engine looks for the views in `~/Views/[Controller]/` and `~/Views/Shared/`.

You need to create your own view engine to make sure the views are searched in area views folder.

Take a look [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx) by Phil Haack.

Comment: Its wired that the default view engine don't do it, as areas is part of the MVC core now.

Comment: @Mendy In that case, maybe you did not register your routes with the `MapAreaRoute` extension method in Global.asax?

Comment: @çağdaş: MapAreaRoute seems to be removed in MVC2 RC2. and as I said, the routing are good since the controller was invoked correctly.

Comment: Source: http://www.dcs-media.com/Archive/maparearoute-removed-from-aspnet-mvc-2-rc-OR

Comment: @Mendy I don't have a chance to test this and I'm taking a wild guess here. But is there any chance you need to provide an `area` keyword when registering your routes? Like this : `routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { area = "SomeArea", controller = "Home", action = "Index" })`

Comment: @çağdaş: I don't think it's not a routing problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today with a simple out of the box VS 2013 MVC 5 project deployed manually to my local instance of IIS on Windows 8.    It turned out that the App Pool being used did not have the proper access to the application (folders, etc.).   After resetting my App Pool identity, it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, this is what was happening for me as well.  It's low hanging fruit to check this first, for future viewers.

Answer (score 2):

1. right click in `index()` method from your controller
2. then click on `goto view`

if this action open index.cshtml?

Your problem is the  IIS pool is  not have  permission  to access the physical     path of the view.

you can  test it by giving permission. for example :- go to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourweb` then  right click on yourweb folder -> property ->security and add  group name everyone and  allow full control to your site .  hope this fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It´s still a problem on the Final release.. .when you create the Area from context menu/Add/Area, visual studio dont put the Controller inside de last argument of the MapRoute method. You need to take care of it, and in my case, I have to put it manually every time I create a new Area.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error even with all the correct MapRoutes in your area registration. Try adding this line to your controller action:

```
If Not ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area") Then
    ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("area", "MyAreaName")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If You can get this error even with all the correct MapRoutes in your area registration and all other basic configurations are fine.

**This is the situation:**

I have used below mentioned code from Jquery file to post back data and then load a view from controller action method.

```
$.post("/Customers/ReturnRetailOnlySales", {petKey: '<%: Model.PetKey %>'});
```

Above jQuery code I **didn't mentioned success callback function**.
What was happened there is after finishing a post back scenario on action method, without routing to my expected view it came back to Jquery side and gave view not found error as above.

Then **I gave a solution like below** and its working without any problem.

```
 $.post("/Customers/ReturnRetailOnlySales", {petKey: '<%: Model.PetKey %>'},
      function (data) {
 var url = Sys.Url.route('PetDetail', { action: "ReturnRetailOnlySalesItems", controller: "Customers",petKey: '<%: Model.PetKey %>'});
 window.location = url;});
```

**Note:** I sent my request inside the success callback function to my expected views action method.Then view engine found a relevant area's view file and load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too; I noticed that I missed to include the view page inside the folder that's name is same with the controller.

Controller: adminController
View->Admin->view1.cshtml

(It was View->view1.cshtml)(there was no folder: Admin)

Answer (score 0):

This error can also surface if your MSI installer failed to actually deploy the file.

In my case this happened because I converted the .aspx files to .cshtml files and visual studio thought these were brand new files and set the build action to none instead of content.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in here, and guess what.... looking at the csproj's xml' structure, I noticed the Content node (inside ItemGroup node) was as "none"... not sure why but that was the reason I was getting the same error, just edited that to "Content" as the others, and it's working.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the `Application_Start()` method inside your project:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Answer (score 0):

I added viewlocationformat to RazorViewEngine and worked for me.

```
ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/Admin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
```