# Azure MVC Angular Project not finding Home page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Locally the website works fine, when deployed to azure we get the view index or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Routeconfig

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "websitename",
            url: "",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "{controller}", action = "{action}", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
```

We are using angularjs and having no problems until deployed to azure other than this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273416/the-view-or-its-master-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-loc)

Answer (score 0):

You define following for home page right?

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DoransData",
        url: "",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
```

Change it to

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DoransData",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
```

Based on your code I think that you could only need following code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```