# Calling action method through AJAX throwing exception to return view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When I am doing AJAX request to controller, Action Method could not find the View which I am trying to return and throwing the exception as shown at end of the question.

Following is the AJAX method calling the Action Method:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "/Courses/AddTime",
            data: { DayName: DayValue, StartTimeValue: 
                   starttimeval,EndTimeValue: EndtimeVal },
           dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            error: function () {
                alert(" An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = '/Courses/listbatch/?BtchTimingid=' + 
                data.ID + "&InsertRetId=" + data.secndid;
            }
        });
```

Following is Action Method and it is called properly from AJAX request but while returning View it is throwing exception.

```
public ActionResult listbatch(string Search_name, int? page, int? 
BtchTimingid = 0, int InsertRetId=0)
    {
   /// There Have some code which is working perfect 


       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_BatchTimingList", model.pageCoursesList);
        else
             return View(model);

    }
```

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr4Pe.png)

> The view 'listbatch' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:
>
> ```
>     ~/Views/Courses/listbatch.aspx
>     ~/Views/Courses/listbatch.ascx
>     ~/Views/Shared/listbatch.aspx
>     ~/Views/Shared/listbatch.ascx
>     ~/Views/Courses/listbatch.cshtml
>     ~/Views/Courses/listbatch.vbhtml
>     ~/Views/Shared/listbatch.cshtml
>     ~/Views/Shared/listbatch.vbhtml
> ```

Comment: Can you try rewriting the question? The english is really hard to follow here...

Comment: calling Action through Json Method and pass Parameter it but at the time of Action called i create same name of View problem is that view is not call that gives Error.

Comment: Phrasing of your question seems tougher than your problem...

Comment: You don't have any views in the location listed. Add a view?

Comment: @amitkumar Your AJAX method posting to url: "/Courses/AddTime",
 but you shown us code for action method: "listbatch"? Better post the correct AJAX call or correct action method, to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273416/the-view-or-its-master-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-loc)

Comment: The success function does `window.location.href = '/Courses/listbatch/` @SivaGopal

Comment: Why in the world are you making an ajax call when you want to redirect - its just pointless. Make a normal submit. And the error is obvious - your making a redirect to `listbatch` and calling `return View(model)` which expect you to have a view named `listbatch.cshtml`. Specify the view name if you want a different view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and got a solution for that after spending 2 days.
Instead of using 
`window.location.href = '/Courses/listbatch/?BtchTimingid=' + 
                data.ID + "&InsertRetId=" + data.secndid;` 
I suggest you to use 
`window.location.href = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("listbatch","Courses",new{BtchTimingid=data.ID, InsertRetId = data.secndid}))`

If you use it without @Html.Raw, your URL will have &amp instead of & for parameters, it shouldn't cause any problem but i don't know why it caused for me and got the same problem that you have i-e The view was not found... So use Html.Raw as well.

Comment: Thanx a Lot Buddy, U r just Awesome its Working Perfetcly...U just i cant express my word..After 3 days it will be success now from Your Solutions....

Comment: But, Buddy one problem is that i can't pass parameter in that it says data does not exist in the current context...

Answer (score 1):

Your view is missing.

```
 public ActionResult listbatch(string Search_name, int? page, int? BtchTimingid = 0, int InsertRetId=0)
 {
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         return PartialView("_BatchTimingList", model.pageCoursesList);
     else
         return View(model);    // <======= HERE (not an AJAX request) =========
 }
```

The following JavaScript does not generate an Ajax request, its a normal GET.

```
 window.location.href = '/Courses/listbatch/?BtchTimingid=' + 
                        data.ID + "&InsertRetId=" + data.secndid;
```

So `View(model)` expects to find `listbatch.cshtml` but cannot (presumably because it is missing) and you get the error message.

You need to create `/Views/Courses/listbatch.cshtml`
Have a look in the Views folder, see if it is there...

Comment: public JsonResult AddTime(CoursesModel Model, string DayName, string StartTimeValue, string EndTimeValue)
        { var resultsss = new { ID = EditBatchTimingId, secndid = retID };
            return Json(resultsss,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }////////Thats  the Json request

Comment: Hi, Above i send u that json request which is passing through controller and after that i pass that windows.location value but my view page is not open it go to that contoller  but still get Error

Comment: Yes. The problem is your view is missing. Create a view at `/Views/Courses/listbatch.cshtml` and try again.

Comment: Dude, i think u cant understand...I already told u that listbatch.cshtml are already created and through Ajax i am calling that action..

Comment: Check the location and filename spelling. When you get that error message, it means the file is not there.