# how can i change routing in asp.net to area/controller/action

Tags: c#

how can i change the default route from home/index to area/controller/action

```
routes.MapRoute(
             null,
             "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            "~/User/UserView/Index"
        );
```

is that wrong?

Comment: you can add `defaults: new { controller = "Area", action = "action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Comment: Was it so hard to google `asp.net mvc areas` and open the first MSDN link?

Comment: I want the action to be the default route in controllers in the area.. I am writing as your sad but give me error

Comment: Just read this basic tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas

Comment: now i haven't any time, if you now that please tell me

Comment: Can't you open the link and scroll down to the code example? It's even faster to copy

Comment: i try it, but give me error again

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to change the default landing for routes.
To do that you would implement something similar to this.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {area = "User" ,controller = "UserView", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If you want this to take precedence over other routes make sure this is mapped before your other routes

Comment: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273416/the-view-or-its-master-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-loc

Comment: That link above might help. I would need to see more of your code to fully understand such as the UserView controller and the index action. My guess is either you haven't created the view inside the proper folder inside the controller inside the area.