# View can not be found even though its present and other views are

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a piece of code which refers to a specific view. The code is

```cs
private ActionResult PrepareSuccessResponse(PaymentProcessingContext paymentContext)
{
    this.RemoveLinkedMemberCookie();
    if (paymentContext.Provider.PaymentProviderType == "Worldpay")
    {
        return View("~/Areas/Payments/Views/Confirmation/WorldPayPaymentResponsePage.cshtml", paymentContext.ConfirmationUrl);
    }
    return Redirect(paymentContext.ConfirmationUrl);
}
```

This however returns the standard error of :

> The view
>   '~/Areas/Payments/Views/Confirmation/WorldPayPaymentResponsePage.cshtml'
>   or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Areas/Payments/Views/Confirmation/WorldPayPaymentResponsePage.cshtml

etc however in the same controller another view in a similar location is returned using these two functions

```cs
private const string FailedResponseViewPath = "~/Areas/Payments/Views/ResponseFailures/";
private static string GetViewPath(string viewName)
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}.cshtml", FailedResponseViewPath, viewName);
}
```

```cs
private ActionResult PrepareFailedProcessingResponse(PaymentProcessingContext paymentContext)
{
    return View(GetViewPath("ProcessingError"), paymentContext);
}
```

The file structure looks like the image below with the file controller being the PaymentMvcController.cs

[image: File Strucutre image]

Comment: Have you tried `return View("~/Areas/Payments/Views/Confirmation/WorldPayPaymentResponsePage.cshtml", paymentContext);`? (insetad of `paymentContext.ConfirmationUrl`) That's the only difference I can see.

Comment: Your controllers folder is nested within the payments folder. You'll have to change your routing. Check the default route within the route config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to the question asked here - [The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273416/the-view-or-its-master-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-loc).
The second argument "paymentContext.ConfirmationUrl" is understood as a path to a master page. To explicity make this the model, you should change the return to this:

```
return View("~/Areas/Payments/Views/Confirmation/WorldPayPaymentResponsePage.cshtml", model:paymentContext.ConfirmationUrl);
```