# The view or its master was not found only on production IIS Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have developed an application in ASP.NET MVC 5.0 + SQL SERVER 2008 and deployed a build in my test environment. It works fine as expected.

Now, I have moved the build to production environment and after login it shows that my home was not found(The view or its master was not found). I have the same configuration in both the IIS Servers.

I am wondering what has been missed?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269220/the-view-index-or-its-master-was-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working because IUSR did not have sufficient privileges.

Please check the link below :
[IUSR Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8)